# Moving contents using batch only if it's held in a subdirectory, not root folder

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm trying to write a script that exclusively moves files from a source folder if they're in a subfolder (IE dayfolders for images) and NOT if the file is just sitting in the root directory. The subdirectories also need to be moved.
So far I just have a basic xcopy script but that's copying the files that don't have a folder as well.
Code below:

```
Set ImageDirectory=C:\Images
Set SMBRootAddress=<Server>
Set SMBImageDestinationFolder=Images

xcopy "%ImageDirectory%" "\\%SMBRootAddress%\%SMBImageDestinationFolder%" /d /i /s /y /r
```

Comment: It appears that you haven't asked a question. All I can see is a single xcopy command asking to copy everything from a location, and a statement that it does exactly that. This site doesn't provide you with code, or links to it, what we do is try to help you fix an issue with your own code. So all I can tell you is that the issue seems to be that your code is not attempting to perform the task you require of it. Have you explored the options of `XCopy`, have you looked at iterating each of the top level subdirectories instead. Have you seen `ForFiles /?`, `For /?`, `RoboCopy /?`, and `Dir /?`.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%"'
 ) DO XCOPY /s /d /y "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%a\" >nul
GOTO :eof
```

That is, simply perform a directory-scan for all required subdirectory names directly under the "local root" directory and then `xcopy` the names found. I haven't preserved your `xcopy` options in my testing.